# Custom Valid URL validation using regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Here,

I am validating URL with following string which either it should be http/https or ip address along with query string and different parenthesis square bracket [] .

I want to prevent following url parenthesis

2)http://192.0.0.0/b4d2f30f-d617-403a-bb2f-dec755d01192?`[publisher[client_id]Id]` - Not Allowed

what should be regular expression to prevent `[publisher[client_id]Id]` sting ?

I'm using following regular expression for above strings

```
var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
        if(!regex .test(str)) {

            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
```

what should be changed code for same?

Please help me for the same.

Comment: Your question doen't tell where your existing regex fails to do its job. Please try to be more specific and try to enable us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to say that I don't want to allow  `[publisher[client_id]Id]`  in query string. now got it ? or need more explanation

Comment: If all you are looking for is `[publisher[client_id]Id]`, then the rest of the string doesn't matter.  Look for that string and ignore the rest.

Comment: Maybe a list of positive and negatives (what should match, what shouldn't) would be helpful

Comment: @ppovoski everything is working but where I have to add regular expression to prevent this `[publisher[client_id]Id]` this should be allow `[publisher_id]`

Comment: @nozzleman  just want to prevent that square bracket should not be  allow  in side [ and ] square bracket

Comment: It's not working the way you think it is working. Everything is getting matched by the `\S` in your regex. The capture groups after that are empty, you could delete them all and still match. So I think much more needs to happen before you can start to think about the nested square brackets problem. For instance I also notice you have a bunch of colons `:` in your regex but there is only the one colon at the very start after `http`. Maybe a tool like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zHrTs8/1) would help you :)

Comment: @funkwurm let me check it's work for me or not

Comment: @funkwurm not work for me

Comment: @HIteshTank you either didn't fully read, or didn't understand my comment. My Regex101 link wasn't to give you a solution, it was to show you that your regex has many more problems than the problem of the nested square brackets.

Comment: @funkwurm Yes, I know that but Where I'm wrong or where to changed code for prevent nested square brackets

Comment: To catch characters, parts between square brackets, but not nested square brackets, you need something like this: `(?:[^[\]]|\[[^[\]]*])*` Basically you say `[^[\]]` -> any character that **isn't** `[` or `]`, **OR** (`|`) `\[[^[\]]*]` -> a square bracket open, then a number of characters that aren't square brackets, and then a closing square bracket. This whole part you put in a non-capturing group (`(?:  )`) and that gets repeated with `*`. Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/4zNv4b/1)

Comment: Can you please tell me where to put this expression code in between my regular express ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var strings = [
   '[publisher[client_id]Id]',
   '[publisher_id]'
];

var pattern = /\[.*\[.*\].*\]/;

strings.forEach(function(string){
   if(pattern.test(string)) {
      console.log(string + " -> matched");
   }
   else {
      console.log(string + " -> not matched");
   }
});
```

Comment: publisher and client id not a static string, I just want to prevent that square bracket should not allow [ and ] square bracket

Comment: You are not getting my exactly problem, I don't want to allow nested square bracket in valid url : for example

http://192.0.0.0/b4d2f30f-d617-403a-bb2f-dec755d01192? `[publisher[client_id]Id]`   it's a invalid url

Comment: @HIteshTank, edited again, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

try this. the first group return url without parameter (withour your publiser, etc)

sorry didn't read it carefully. try that one and return true if valid

## edited

```js
var t1 = "htts:/192.0.0.0/b4d2f30f-d617-403a-bb2f-dec755d01192?[publisher[client_id]]";
var t2 = "https://192.0.0.0/b4d2f30f-d617-403a-bb2f-dec755d01192";
var t3 = "https://192.0.0 .0/b4d2f30f-d617-403a-bb2f-dec755d01192?[publisher[client_id]]";
var t4 = "https://192.0.0 .0/b4d2f30f-d617-403a-bb2f-dec755d01192?name=[publisher[client_id]]";
var t5 = "https://192.0.0 .0/b4d2f30f-d617-403a-bb2f-dec755d01192?foo=bar&name=[publisher[client_id]]";

function check(str) {
  var url = /((http[s]?:\/\/){1,1}(\w+[-.\/]{0,1}\w?)*)/g,
    p = /([\?\&](\w+=){0,1}\[\w+\[\w+\]\w*\])/g;
  /*check for url*/
  if (!url.test(str)) {
    return "invalid url";
  }
  /*check for [userid[userid]]*/
  return p.test(str) ? "invalid" : "valid";
}
document.body.innerHTML = check(t1) + "</br>";
document.body.innerHTML += check(t2) + "</br>";
document.body.innerHTML += check(t3) + "</br>";
document.body.innerHTML += check(t4) + "</br>";
document.body.innerHTML += check(t5) + "</br>";
```

regards

Comment: but what about nested square bracket to prevent it

Comment: `[string[sting]]` nested square bracket should not be allowed it's return false but still getting true

Comment: using running code is better. i edited again. please review it
there are 2 filter:
1. to check wheter is valid url or not
2. to check wheter it contains [user[userid]] or not

Comment: @RizliDPrast : I have added this string `asdsa=[publisher[client_id]id]` it's also not invalid query string but as per your express it allow this instead of invalid Could you please help me for the same ?

Comment: Working, Thank you so much. @RizliDPrast

Comment: @hitesh-tank, Im glad it can help. Consider either set the answer as accepted or use vote so that other can find it usefull too

regards

Comment: I tried but Can't do that because of reputation. I need help of you to increase my question votes

Comment: @riskiDprast https://192.0.0.0&12332?  not allow the character & before the character ? such as `&1343?`  can you please help me for the same

Comment: try to change to `/((http[s]?:\/\/){1,1}([\w+-.\/&]{0,1})*)/g`
you can play with regex with online editor tool easily such as in [the one i used](https://regex101.com/)
Also,  i guess you will still need more validation for url like not allowing space `(/\S/)` etc

regards